# How to change MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_SUBTEXT if exists two MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

Tags: nsis

I have managed to customize the message shown in the title / subtitle after installation:

```
!define APP_NAME 'Test15'

name ${APP_NAME}
outfile '${APP_NAME}.exe'
showinstdetails show
InstallDir '$PROGRAMFILES\${APP_NAME}'

!include 'mui.nsh'

Var CompletedText
CompletedText $CompletedText


Var MUI_HeaderText
Var MUI_HeaderSubText
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_TEXT "$MUI_HeaderText"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_SUBTEXT "$MUI_HeaderSubText"


!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"


Section "One"
    MessageBox MB_OK "Section One"
SectionEnd



Section -"Post"
  ;MessageBox MB_OK "Section Post"
  StrCpy $CompletedText "My custom text"
  StrCpy $MUI_HeaderText "My custom header text"
  StrCpy $MUI_HeaderSubText "My custom header subText"
  ;MessageBox MB_OK "OUTING Section Post"
SectionEnd
```

My problem is that when I need to add a second part installation (**it is a new mandatory requirement**), and then not get modify / customize messages title / subtitle shown at the end:

```
!define APP_NAME 'Test15'

name ${APP_NAME}
outfile '${APP_NAME}.exe'
showinstdetails show
InstallDir '$PROGRAMFILES\${APP_NAME}'

!include 'mui.nsh'

Var CompletedText
CompletedText $CompletedText


Var MUI_HeaderText
Var MUI_HeaderSubText
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_TEXT "$MUI_HeaderText"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_SUBTEXT "$MUI_HeaderSubText"


!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

;This my second part instalation!!
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"


Section "One"
   MessageBox MB_OK "Section One"
SectionEnd



Section -"Post"
  ;MessageBox MB_OK "Section Post"
  StrCpy $CompletedText "My custom text"
  StrCpy $MUI_HeaderText "My custom header text"
  StrCpy $MUI_HeaderSubText "My custom header subText"
  ;MessageBox MB_OK "OUTING Section Post"
SectionEnd
```

Now, the same message is always displayed at the end for Title/Subtitle: "Installation Complete" // "Setup was completed successfully.". Nevertheless, the 'completed' text value is modified successfully ("My custom text").

Please, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the MUI documentation carefully you will find this in the "Page settings" section:

> Page settings apply to a single page and should be set before inserting a page macro. The same settings can be used for installer and uninstaller pages. **You have to repeat the setting if you want it to apply to multiple pages**.

Only the defines listed under "Interface settings" are global.

```
!include MUI.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Install page #1"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Foo foo foo"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_TEXT "Did part 1"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_SUBTEXT "..."
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Install page #2"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Bar bar bar!"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_TEXT "All done"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_SUBTEXT "ZZZzzz.."
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```